# Why are some questions locked while others are deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, locked-posts, historical-lock

Browsing my old ★'d questions, I noticed that several, while very popular, have been deemed off-topic.

But [some are locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature), remaining visible for everyone to see, while [others are deleted outright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes). (Luckily, I can still see and enjoy them, but others aren't so fortunate.)

Is there some reasoning behind the difference?

Comment: FWIW your second example was deleted before the historical lock existed.

Answer (score 4):

"Strangest language feature" and "Great programming quotes" are two great example questions because they fall so close to the "Does this question teach me anything that could make me better at my job? Can I learn something from it?" criteria laid out in the [Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) blog post. They each just barely fall on either side of that line, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about that post. It's often a difficult balance. Nowadays, I think off-topic questions tend to get downvoted/closed faster, so they have less of a chance to excel in criteria #2 and #3. Nonetheless, I would absolutely vote to undelete "Great programming quotes"... if I could (if it hadn't been closed by a moderator)!

Comment: @jtbandes Not just any moderator, but a co-founder of Stack Overflow. :) I don't really mind that one being deleted, since it's so easy to find lists of programming quotes through Google. Contrast that with the other question, where a lot of people took the time to explain the strange language features. There's a lot more to learn there.

Comment: Google works fine, sure, but I find comment threads to be an indispensable source of additional content, and that's not something you find everywhere. When I think of [top questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes), this is the kind of thing I would want to see. (Mind you, as Jeff said in the blog post, *only a limited amount*!)

Comment: @jtbandes Unfortunately questions like "Favorite programming joke" and "Best programmer t-shirt" were pushing down the great technical content that's at the top of that list now.