# Should questions with useful answers be deleted even if off topic?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I was browsing vim tips and stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735/useful-vim-features)

It has been deleted because it is relatively off-topic but I have enough rep to see it anyways. The thing is, those answers are great! I'm getting real value out of reading them and what a shame that people with lower reputation cannot.

I've voted to undelete but really, as a policy, isn't simply deleting questions with well thought out answers like this antithetical to SO's purpose of building up a knowledge database?

**Edit:** So hey, lots of downvotes but not a lot of actual discussion. I'm not talking about one specific question. I'm saying, isn't the fact that useful answers can end up being only usable by a small portion of the SO population an obvious hole in policy that we should try to come up with a solution for?

**Edit 2:** Really unclear why this is continuing to get downvoted. Are people saying that they don't see this as a problem? That it is not our task here to try to find a solution? That the question is poorly worded?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267044/why-are-some-questions-locked-while-others-are-deleted

Comment: It's asking to compile a hit-list of features. And I wonder why it only got 36 answers, most of them nearly completely useless.

Comment: @gnat I understand why it's off topic but the first few answers, especially the top one are fantastic. Why should it be that only members with high rep can learn from it?

Comment: Simply because that's more for a blog or such. Though, it would be great if there was something similar on SE. And hopefully everyone understands that it's not off-topic because it's asking about a tool. Certain questions about vim would be completely on-topic for SO but too many people fail to see that and close questions unnecessarily.

Comment: @Deduplicator whether or not the question is quality or if a lot of answers are crappy, that doesn't really address the question I'm posing here. Ideally we don't want to send any useful information into the void. We should sort (vote/close/delete low quality things) it and categorize it (tag/move to different SE), but SE is ultimately about making a knowledge database, and deleting useful information runs counter to that goal.

Comment: as far as I know, [historical lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/historical-lock/info) is the only reliable way to save off-topic question from deletion

Answer (score 6):

They may *well* be great answers but, if the question is unsuitable for SO, it doesn't really matter how great the answers are.

What I would consider is "lifting" the best answers and then creating a blog article elsewhere listing them, hopefully attributing to SO at some point.

Then the answers are still out there somewhere but hopefully on a more suitable site.

Comment: Right, but is this really the correct policy? After all, this puts the onus to act on users. Specifically those with enough reputation to see the question. And with a blog. And with time to write a post. And who somehow get it to pop up in search results. So it won't happen and a useful answer ends up not being seen by many people who would like to see it. I would propose that highly rated answers have a much higher bar for deletion but maybe a better solution is to have an "orphaned purgatory" where good off-topic questions with no obvious better place should go until a better SE comes along

Comment: I'd prefer to migrate these questions instead of deleting them, but Stack Overflow [doesn't allow this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days) in many cases.

Answer (score 3):

That post is really just a reorganized manual. The actual ***[vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_toc.html)*** is rather complete and easy to navigate. Further, there is an entire ***[vim cheatsheet](http://tnerual.eriogerg.free.fr/vimqrc.html)*** available which outlines basically the entirety of the features discussed in that post in a more compact style.

The Q&A format is not designed to be used as a blog. Forcing content which should be a blog into the Q&A format bucks the convention here and as a result often is removed.

**There is a place for content like that in largely active tags, and that is the tag wiki**. Tag wikis are meant to be a midpoint between posts and documentation, and can easily house some of the most popular shortcuts shown in that post.

Further, the tag wiki is where I collected the first two links shown in this post.

Comment: So..I'm not sure what you're saying you're saying the correct thing to do in situations like this is for useful answers to get moved to the tag wiki?